# Cloning with event handlers using deepWithDataAndEvents?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I am reading the .clone() documentation http://api.jquery.com/clone/ trying to learn how to clone objects for my project... I have an event handler .click() function that adds an active state to the cloned block. Take a look at this fiddle it makes more sense.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/KRg23/2/

Right now it's just in beta stages, eventually I will clone the block when a button is clicked (NOT ON LOAD).. but for now the first two bars are coded by default, and the last two are cloned on load, as I said when ready for production there will only be one element and it will be cloned on a button click (just to fill you in)

Lastly let me explain why I need to clone an event handler, in the case of the fiddle it does not add an `.active` class to the `.block` on `.click()`, I assume it's not doing so because like the documentation says *"Normally, any event handlers bound to the original element are not copied to the clone. The optional withDataAndEvents parameter allows us to change this behavior,"* I just don't see where they explain *withDataAndEvents*..

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/KRg23/2/

Comment: Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmLKq/ All I did was change `clone()` to `clone(true)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation said:

*"withDataAndEvents (default: false)
Type: Boolean"*

Which means that you can pass true or false as `.clone()` parameter.

```
var clone = jQuery('#sortable .block').clone(true);
```

This will clone elements with the event bindings.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KRg23/3/

Comment: Awesome, 4 letters that was it :) Thanks!!